# What are the conditions for a data to be represented by GBM?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, random-walk

So my question is as follows. ***State the conditions a data have to satisfy in order to be represented by a Geometric Brownian motion. Does your data satisfy this condition? Produce appropriate evidence to support your answer.***

I have written the following as the answer.

•   Since relative change in S is normally distributed, S will be log-normally distributed with parameters μ and σ.

•   Over a time t, he random component of a Geometric Brownian motion is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance t.

•   The increments St1 – St2, St2 – St3, St3 – St4, etc… are jointly independent random variables.

•   Distribution of St1 – St2 = Distribution of St1+1 – St2+1 = Distribution of Stn+k – St2+k . That is distribution depends only on the interval of time between the processes.

***Is anything missing? How do I test it using a data that I have?***

Comment: If you want to test if a time series $(S_n)_{n\geq 0}$ follows a GBM you could: take $X_n=\log (S_n/S_{n-1})$, estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to fit $\mathcal{N}(\mu-0.5\sigma^2, \sigma^2)$ to the values, and check stationarity and independence of $X_n$ by one of the many tests: augmented Dickey-Fuller test, KPSS test, and Phillips-Perroj test for stationarity, and e.g. Ljung-Box test for independence.

Comment: @NapD.Lover http://storage.thanksforthehelp.com/cfile/assessment-task-2-dataset-uu5llx5v.txt  This is the data that I have. I have imported this to R. But this data if fluctuating up and down and doesn't seem to fit well to the GBM model.

Comment: If you have already imported the data to R you may run these tests, fit the distribution and assess the outcomes as to whether GBM is a good fit or not. Every test I mentioned is readily available in base R or well-established packages and there is fairly good documentation for one to be resourceful with...

Comment: @NapD.Lover Just by looking at the data can you conclude on something?